# I can't access the second level of a json after passing the data for props, in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I make a request with axios in a saga, which I receive in a component through the reduction in the mapStateToProps, if I go through the data in that component I can access any level but if I send it on props I can only access the first level of the json and on the second level I get Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

component where I trigger the action and receive the state, and I pass the props:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Auxiliary';
import Products from '../../Components/ProductsSencillo/Products'
import { Grid } from 'styled-css-grid';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { productComplete } from '../../redux/actions/productAction'
import reducerProduct from '../../redux/modules/reducers/productReducer'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class ProductBuilder extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.handleListar();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
        <Grid columns="repeat(auto-fit,minmax(45px,1fr))">
          <Products products={this.props.state} />
        </Grid>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state: state.productReducer.productos.productos
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleListar: bindActionCreators(productComplete, dispatch),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductBuilder);
```

component where I receive the props and the mappings:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from './Product/Product'
import { Cell } from 'styled-css-grid';

class Products extends Component {
  render() {
    return {
      this.props.products.map(pro => {
        return <Cell width={3}>< Product
          image={pro.imagen_principal.ruta}
          name={pro.nombre}
        />
        </Cell>
      })
    }
  }
}

export default Products;
```

error that throws me:

[image: Error]

API:

[image: API Error]

Comment: Can you add the reducer code here ?

Answer (score 1):

When accessing "route" you have to first check if the value is present in the object that component receives.

**Try this:**

```
<Product image={pro.imagen_principal && pro.imagen_principal.ruta}/>
```

Hope this helps!